# Proportional edit mode can't be activated

Tags: vertex-groups

Need to grab that selected vertex that you can see on the screenshot using "Proportional Editing". However, even though I activated this mode, every time when I press "G" and try to grab the vertex, the circle of proportional editing does not appear. Initially, there was a thought that circle is large a little bit so I was trying to use a scroll to make it more small, but there is not circle at all. How to solve this issue?
[image]

Comment: Hello :). Does proportional editing work when enabled through the Pop-up panel (where you adjust the distance)?

Comment: Hello! :) @JachymMichal Yes, it works. Actually, I have found what was the problem after you said about the Pop-up panel. I didn't pay much attention to that 3D cursor. It was displaced.

Answer (score -1):

3D cursor should be aligned with the object you edit. [image]

Comment: Hey :). That's weird. The 3D cursor should only matter when set as *Pivot Point* (which it isn't). Anyways, glad you got it working.